# How do I connect to local instance in sql server 2012 express Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

[image: My picture]

I have installed management studio. But it is not showing any services in the Sql server Configuration manager.
Please give me the solution

Comment: Have you checked to see if the SQL Server services are running under Windows Services?

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server?

Comment: You probably installed only the SQL Server client (SS Management Studio). Try to find a package containing the SQL Server engine as well.